# Is there a way to have asynchronous communication between a C++ and C# application through Protobuf?

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

The scenario I'm thinking of is as following: Imagine there's two functions within two different programs, one of which in C++ and the other in C#. For now I'll call these functions *cppFunc()* and *csFunc()*.

Say *cppFunc()* requests an identification token from *csFunc()*, which could normally be obtained through a **protobuf** generated binary file. *cppFunc()* however, needs to confirm this token and then return it when confirmed.

This scenario would mean *cppFunc()* would have to wait for *csFunc()* to be executed, so it can send a token. Is there any way this can be done? I've had a look at *gRPC* because this seemed like the most plausible solution, the way I understand it the request respone structure there between the client and server wouldn't really function between two clientside applications. Granted ofcourse this could be a wrong assumption of me to make.

**Edit**:
For extra context. I'm assuming here these are two different programs/processes (One an entirely seperate C++ based program the other a C# program through the use of the Unity game engine). Ideally the communication here would be possible both between devices and on  a single computer. The programs are basically both frontend applications put on top of an already existing C++ backend. So they would both do the same because they both use the same backend.

Another example of the type of communication here would be that I'd like to have the ability to process a .obj in the C++ program, and send it's data to the C# program. I have already found a way to do this, but only through the means of me compiling and executing the C++ program, manually dragging the binary file to the C# program and reconstructing it there. In the ideal scenario you would process the .obj file on the C++ side and have it available in the C# program right after without having to manually do anything with the generated files.

The issue here being that it's not just merely sending object data from point a to point b, but also needing this multi directional token identification system.

Comment: The context is unclear here. Are these two separate processes, or one process using interop? I definitely wouldn't start adding gRPC if there's only a single process. If there are two processes, you *could* communicate between them using gRPC, but we really need more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "clientside"? You can absolutely run a server and a client on the same computer, but gRPC is primarily intended for inter *process* communication. You could use within a process, but then you might want to take a look at something like c++/cli instead.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Does this edit provide the context you guys need? Please let me know

Comment: If the goal is just to access some functionality in c++, Consider using a .net library or porting the c++ functionality. Keeping to a single process/platform tend to make many things simpler.

Comment: @JonasH I'm basically trying to make a second front-end to an application that already exists within C++. So they would both function similarly side by side, but one works through Unity and the other simply within the C++ application. I guess I didn't really specify that either. Because of this porting the functionality wouldn't really do the trick here.

Comment: Protocol Buffers is basically a method of serialising / deserialising data to / from (platform and language agnostic) buffer of bytes. The gRPC is crud built on top of it and that assumes certain architecture of "service" and "clients". But nothing forces you to use gRPC for whatever you do.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I get what you mean, but I was wondering whether I could use something like gRPC in the specific usecase I mentioned here, or if there were any other good solutions with which I can achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: You could definetly use gRPC for the described use case, like (probably) any other RPC framework. But both sides need running servers/services to listen to incoming protobuf requests. The services could use interprocess communication if they are running on the same machine, and normal HTTP/2 communication otherwise. But like Jon Skeet said, there might be easier solutions for your problem.